# pygame snake: no game over when object passes boundary

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

Making a basic snake game in Python 2.7 using pygame...

I set up a game over event to happen for when snake goes past the window screen. But, when it goes past the point(s) of the boundary, nothing happens.
Any suggestions?

Below are the lines of code I think I would need to change and a link to a gist on GitHub for the rest of my program.

`# BOUNDARIES
       if lead_x >= display_width or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= display_height or lead_y < 0:
          gameOver = True`

[link to pygame snake gist](https://gist.github.com/jo3t3ch3m/0737f81db42b975018e9d6f2d6883d1d)

Comment: use `print()` to check values in variables and see if this part is even executed. Maybe you have different values than you expect, or this part is never executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this code inside `for event` loop so it is executed only in specific moments - when you click key, move mouse, etc. You have to change indention. It has to be outside `for event` loop

---

**BTW:** after you change indention you get error:

```
 NameError: name 'mesg' is not defined
```

because you have argument `msg` but you use `mesg` to render text.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks! I knew it had to be something simple like that - two (or more) pairs of eyes are better than one